# How can I use two lists together?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have 2 lists; materials and their corresponding amounts.  
 As an example The lists are:`words=["banana","apple","orange","bike","car"]` and `numbers=[1,5,2,5,1]`. 
 With these lists how can I determine which one has the least amount and which one has the most amount of items. 
 I do not know where to start Thank you!

Comment: See Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Work through tutorials/examples on dictionaries or the the `zip` iterator.

Comment: In this example, the greatest amount is of `apple` or `bike`?

Comment: @Prune thanks for your advice I appreciate it! However this is not my assignment, I was just trying to get help to understand what to do.

Comment: `sorted(zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0][0]`

Comment: @susenj Both have the greatest amount of numbers , this is just a random example. I am trying to understand the concept of using two lists together

Comment: @JaredSmith can I ask you why you used zip instead of dictionary solving this problem

Comment: Okay, not homework -- the underlying principles still apply.  Look up materials on stepping through two lists, and in finding extreme values.  Post code, not "show me how to do this".

Comment: @Prune Okay I will be more careful in the future time. Again my aim is to understand the concept, not the code. This was just a random example

Comment: Excellent.  Concepts come from existing documentation; Stack Overflow is mostly for repairing problem code, not concept tutorials.

Comment: @Prune Oh okay thank you, that explains why you thought it was an assignment. Next time I will ask an error about my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping things simple: If you just want one least and one most amount item

```py
words=["banana","apple","orange","bike","car"] 
numbers=[1,5,2,5,1]

# get least and most amounts using max and min
least_amount = min(numbers)
most_amount=max(numbers)

# get fruit with least amount using index
index_of_least_amount = numbers.index(least_amount)
index_of_most_amount = numbers.index(most_amount)

# fruit with least amount
print(words[index_of_least_amount])

# fruit with most amount
print(words[index_of_most_amount])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` to match corresponding words and numbers:

```
>>> words = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "bike", "car"]
>>> numbers = [1, 5, 2, 5, 1]
>>> list(zip(words, numbers))
[('banana', 1), ('apple', 5), ('orange', 2), ('bike', 5), ('car', 1)]
```

If you `zip` them to `(number, word)` pairs, you can use `min` and `max` directly on those pairs to get the min/max combination:

```
>>> min(zip(numbers, words))
(1, 'banana')
>>> max(zip(numbers, words))
(5, 'bike')
```

Or create a `dict` from the `(word, number)` pairs and use `min` and `max` on that. This only gives you the word, but you can get the corresponding number from the dict:

```
>>> d = dict(zip(words, numbers))
>>> d
{'apple': 5, 'banana': 1, 'bike': 5, 'car': 1, 'orange': 2}
>>> min(d, key=d.get)
'banana'
>>> max(d, key=d.get)
'apple'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import itemgetter

words = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "bike", "car"]
numbers = [1, 5, 2, 5, 1]

min_item = min(zip(words, numbers), key=itemgetter(1))
max_item = max(zip(words, numbers), key=itemgetter(1))

print("The min item was {} with a count of {}".format(*min_item))
print("The max item was {} with a count of {}".format(*max_item))
```

Output:

```
The min item was banana with a count of 1
The max item was apple with a count of 5
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be using a dictionary or a list of tuples for things like this:

```
words=["banana","apple","orange","bike","car"]
numbers=[1,5,2,5,1]
dicti = {}

for i in range(len(words)):
    dicti[words[i]] = numbers[i]

print(dicti["banana"]) #1
```

resulting dict

```
{'banana': 1, 'apple': 5, 'orange': 2, 'bike': 5, 'car': 1}
```

---

heres how you can get the max and mins in there using a list of tuples

```
words=["banana","apple","orange","bike","car"]
numbers=[1,5,2,5,1]

numMax = max(numbers)
numMin = min(numbers)
print([x for x,y in zip(words, numbers) if y == numMax ]) #maxes
print([x for x,y in zip(words, numbers) if y == numMin ]) #mins
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the products having least and the max amount

Comment: he can use it to answer that, and im working on making a simple example to show them.

Comment: This calls `min` and `max` once for each element to check, making it `O(n**2)` work. Best to compute the `min` and `max` outside the listcomp.

Comment: oh i didnt think of that, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
words = ["banana","apple","orange","bike","car"]
numbers = [1, 5, 2, 5, 1]

# Make a dict, is easier
adict = {k:v for k,v in zip(words, numbers)}

# Get maximums and minimums
min_value = min(adict.values()) 
max_value = max(adict.values())

# Here are the results, both material and values. You have also those which are tied
min_materials = {k,v for k,v in adict if v == min_value}
max_materials = {k,v for k,v in adict if v == max_value}
```

Comment: FYI, since no transformation of keys or values is needed, `{k:v for k,v in zip(words, numbers)}` can become just `dict(zip(words, numbers))`.